# Made NavMeshAgents to avoid certain agent

Tags: unity-game-engine

So about my problem, I am making some AI that follows other agents, and avoids each other.

That works fine, but when the agent A chases the agent B, and agent A gets closest try to avoid agent B, so how can I solve it?

If I disable the avoidance, then he will not avoid other agents, and I don't want that.

If I disable the avoidance when it gets closest, then we will have the same undesired effect as before.

So does there exist a way like in collision to say, agent A don't avoid Agent B, but be sure to avoid other agents?

Comment: What do you want to happen when they get close?

Comment: hi actually they attack each others, so looks strange when agent A follow agent B in order to attack him, and when gets close made a strange change of direction trying to avoid him, that looks bad visually

Comment: I've made a comment or answer in the past that goes along the lines of: "What does it mean to *avoid* a point on the navmesh? Can the agent move towards its avoid target in order to run past it? What about loops, is it acceptable/preferable to run in circles away from its avoid target? You need to answer these questions and write your own AI for this."

Answer (score 0):

When the agent is in range of the agent who shall be attacked. You could set the Agents target as Agent B.